# Cannot find the ID of an item in HTML code

Tags: html, selenium

I'm attempting to find the id of the proceed to checkout button for a bot I am working on for my mom on best buys website . the button however, appears to have it's ID hidden and I cannot figure out how to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

The checkout screen:
[image]

The div class:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for help with the selector? If so try this xpath:

```
//*[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout']
```

Comment: I am attempting to find the div that includes this as I am using python selenium to click the button and getting the error " element not interactable" ```#driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='checkoutButton_2PqYr']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout']").click()```

Comment: add tha a element: //*[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout']/a